# How to remove error in providing input to external process in Groovy

Tags: groovy, inputstream, external-process

I am trying to give user name and password to an external process in groovy. But I am having some trouble in that as its failing with error.

```
String username=params.get("u")
String password=params.get("x")
command1="external_process "+username+"/"+password+" <"+tempfilepath0
p = command1.execute()
p.out<<username
p.out<<password
```

Its still asking for username and password. So what should i do to resolve this??

Comment: Would that process be SSH?

Comment: That process might be any external process trying to access any application using username and password. And then would execute some commands written in file on that application.